# I am trying to write an app in Okta that will use OIDC for authentication in my webapp for multiple clients

Tags: node.js, passport.js, okta

I have a node.js application that has a user database behind it.  I would like to use OIDC with Okta (using passport) to help my users utilize their own Okta dashboards to automatically sign into our application.  I have written all the code and I can sign in from my dev instance and authenticate correctly.  The issue I have is that whenever another organization would like to use my app they would add it to their dashboard, but get a new client_secret.  How do I have multiple client secrets I trust in passport or is this approach incorrect?

I have passport working for a single instance.

Comment: I think it's not specifically Okta related but a generic question around OIDC and Passport